# TEXTJOIN with ARRAYFORMULA Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, array-formulas

I have a little problem getting the array from the function below. When the criterion of the IF function is range (At the site of B11) it stops working and returns just one not conected value. How to get the array result?

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(" ", TRUE,ARRAYFORMULA(IF('Sheet1'!$B$2:$B15 = B11, 'Sheet1'!$D$2:$D15, ""))))
```

LINK to Sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QQGcPKI895NpwM-9oXccs8Ln4RWXAPaqVq5IBKllKFE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: @player0 
I added a sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A&"", 
 TRIM(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY({J2:J&"♥", L2:L&","}, 
 "select max(Col2) 
  where Col2 <> ',' 
  group by Col2 
  pivot Col1"),,9^9))), ",$", ), "♥")), 2, 0)))
```

[image]