# join() or query() substitute for textjoin() in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

Would like to come up with a modified textjoin that can operate together withan array formula, while ignoring empty cells.

I have a formula that is close but it combines data inside of cells without a space.

| A1 | B1 | C1 | D1 | E1 | text join | Formula | Desired |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| red | white |  | blue white | red white | red, white, blue white, red white | red, white, **bluewhite**, **redwhite**, red, white, **bluewhite, redwhite** | red, white, blue white, red white, red, white, blue white, red white |
|  | green | yellow |  |  | green, yellow | green, yellow, green, yellow | green, yellow, green, yellow |
| white |  |  |  | white | white, white | white, white, white, white | white, white, white, white |
|  | white |  |  |  | white | white, white | white, white |

Formula in G1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR( 
    REGEXREPLACE(
            REGEXREPLACE(
                REGEXREPLACE(
                    SUBSTITUTE(
                        flatten(query(transpose(A3:F)&", ",,columns(A3:F))),
                        " ",
                        ""
                    ),
                    "\s|,",
                    ""
                ),
                "^+|+$",
                ""
            ),
            "\b{1,}\b",
            ", "
        )
    ))
```

Alternative approach is using map

```
MAP(A3:A,B3:B,LAMBDA(a,b,TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,{a,b})) )
```

but this requires more editing every time you wish to adapt it

Unsure if my formula may be adapted to fix the issue with eliminating the whitespace between words while maintaining the remainder of the function?

maybe [@player0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64849735/textjoin-with-arrayformula-google-sheets) has some magic he can add here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use BYROW in order to use TEXTJOIN in each row:

```
=BYROW(A3:F,LAMBDA(r,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,r)))
```

I don't know if you actually need that F column, if you just need to have everything joined by two, you can use:

```
=BYROW(A3:E,LAMBDA(r,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,r,r)))
```

[image]

Comment: excellent and elegant & can combine with arrayformula()

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```cpp
=BYROW(A2:E,LAMBDA(r,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,r,r)))
```