# Join unique values by row using Lambda() in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Would like to come up with a modified textjoin using that can operate together with arrayformula(), ignoring empty cells

| 1 | 2 | 3 | Expected result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| one | one |  | one |
| one |  | two | one, two |
| one | two | three | one, two, three |
|  |  |  |  |

You can use BYROW in order to use TEXTJOIN in each row:

```
=BYROW(A3:F,LAMBDA(r,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,r)))
```

But can this be modified to only select unique values?

This attempt doesnt work:

```
=BYROW(array, LAMBDA(r, TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, UNIQUE(r))))
```

See also:

1. [TEXTJOIN with ARRAYFORMULA Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64849735/textjoin-with-arrayformula-google-sheets)
2. [join() or query() substitute for textjoin() in google sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78064618/join-or-query-substitute-for-textjoin-in-google-sheets)

Answer (score 1):

The [`UNIQUE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10522653?hl=en) function has an optional parameter `by_column` that can be used to filter the data by columns rather than by rows.

[image]

```cpp
=BYROW(A3:F,LAMBDA(r,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,UNIQUE(r,1))))
```